# Playing MP4 from my android app is very choppy

Tags: android, video, mp4

I have a strange problem with my Hackberry board with Android 4.0.4, I have to play a video in full screen, but the video is very choppy, very slow if played from my app. If I play the same mp4 video on the default media player all is fine and fast. The same apk on my Samsung S3 is also fast inside the app and with the media player.

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
           android:id="@+id/surface_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the code I use to play the video

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.decart));
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

and the manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:persistent="true" 
    android:largeHeap="true" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Any idea?

I also have made a test, if I put my video in a SD-CARD all is ok, if I use the file inside raw resource folde I have the problem on video. The following seems to be the solution, but is not a good solution for me.

```
//NOT OK
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.decart));

// OK
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/decart.mp4").toString()));
```

Best regards to everyone

Comment: does the quality of the video matter, i mean maybe the video is in HD, so the processor can't handle it good.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the problem from here it has nothing to do with the video itself. It's simply the throughput you can achieve from both sources. The android.resource:// stuff seems to have performance issues, the simple file access not.

You could try to simply read the file from both sources, measure the read speed and see if the culprit is really the I/O throughput.